# Error "Could not find 'openssl.exe' when Installing Scrapy

Tags: python, windows, windows-8, scrapy

On a Windows 8 64-bit Machine, The error 'Could not find 'openssl.exe'' repeatedly pops up, preventing the install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a 64-bit Machine, you have to use the 64-bit version of pyOpenSSL, which is not included in the default downloads page that most Scrapy tutorials provide. Check out [this link](https://tahoe-lafs.org/source/tahoe-lafs/deps/tahoe-lafs-dep-eggs/README.html) to find the proper 64-bit installation of pyOpenSSL. After that, the program should not have that error anymore.